# Mockito - Unfinished Stubbing

Tags: java, mockito, stubbing

I'm getting an `UnfinishedStubbingException` with the following code:

```
Mockito.when(repository.findAll(Mockito.any(Pageable.class)))
    .thenReturn(BusinessEntityMockGenerator.createPageResponse(bd, null));
```

The strange thing is I was not getting this error with Spring Boot 1.3. I just upgraded to Spring Boot 2.0 and now I'm getting this error.

Any ideas? Thanks!

EDIT: It's also giving the error `Pageable must not be null!`.

Comment: Your issue is not very clear. The exceptions are not accumulative but if you catch them. So what did it raise ?  `UnfinishedStubbingException` or `Pageable must not be null` Please present the  `BusinessEntityMockGenerator` class too. It may matter.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what BusinessEntityMockGenerator is doing, but try to separate the method call for the page response:

```
Object toReturn = BusinessEntityMockGenerator.createPageResponse(bd, null);
Mockito.when(repository.findAll(Mockito.any(Pageable.class))).thenReturn(toReturn);
```

You can also try:

```
Object toReturn = BusinessEntityMockGenerator.createPageResponse(bd, null);
Mockito.doReturn(toReturn).when(repository).findAll(Mockito.any(Pageable.class))
```